# JSON removing fields from file with RegEx

Tags: regex, json

I want to remove the flavor and pkgT fields from a JSON files with each line formatted as follows:

```
     "jobID":2598752", "account":"TG-CCR120014", "user":"charngda", "pkgT":{"mvapich2-new/1.2":{"libA":["libmpich.so.1.1"], "flavor":["default:pgi/7.2-5"]}}, "startEpoch":"1338608868", "runTime":"48", "execType":"user:binary", "exec":"IOR", "numNodes":"4", "sha1":"755187bd8550881bb0c9951822e74a9a53c8d0f3", "execEpoch":1336757832, "execModify":"Fr, Ma, 1, 12:37:1, 2012", "startTime":"Fr, Ju,  , 22:47:4, 2012", "numCores":"64", "sizeT":{"bss":"36224", "text":"3502656", "data":"128944"}},
```

So how can I construct a regular expression to remove these fields?  Thanks!!!!

OK I fixed the missing quote in the JobID field so now what?

Comment: Don't do it with a regex.

Comment: Why don't you parse it into native data structures, snip out the bits you don't want, and then serialize it back to JSON?

Comment: Why don't you just parse the JSON, remove it, and then stringify it again?

Comment: Well I tried to fix the file as I needed using awk however the fields are not numbered consistently since some have the flavor and pkgT fields and others do not.

Comment: How would I go about parsing it differently?  I am not experienced at all with text manipulation and I have spent almost 3 weeks trying to get this thing formatted correctly for my PhD research project and getting into hot water with my adviser.

Answer (score 0):

Since your string is already in JSON, why would you use regular expressions? That is just over-complicating the issue. Instead, take your string and parse it with JSON with `JSON.parse()`.

```
var str = '{ "jobID": "2598752", "account": "TG-CCR120014", "user": "charngda", "pkgT": { "mvapich2-new/1.2": { "libA": ["libmpich.so.1.1"], "flavor": ["default:pgi/7.2-5"] } }, "startEpoch": "1338608868", "runTime": "48", "execType": "user:binary", "exec": "IOR", "numNodes": "4", "sha1": "755187bd8550881bb0c9951822e74a9a53c8d0f3", "execEpoch": 1336757832, "execModify": "Fr, Ma, 1, 12:37:1, 2012", "startTime": "Fr, Ju,  , 22:47:4, 2012", "numCores": "64", "sizeT": { "bss": "36224", "text": "3502656", "data": "128944" } }';
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
```

Then proceed to delete the keys.

```
delete obj['flavor'];
delete obj['pkgT'];
//returns true if deleted, false if failed
```

Then you can turn the JSON back into a string.

```
var newstr = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Comment: I assume this is using Javascript.  AS I said I have absolutely no experience with JSON files, and this stupid thing is giving me nightmares,

Comment: Do you recommend an IDE to use to construct this?

Comment: Sweet!! I used NetBeans and the code you recommended, but this is simply one line of a 7000 line json file how do I process the entire thing?